# Mod value calculation using XPathNavigator

Tags: c#, xpathnavigator

I am calculating mod of value "89001012012341234" using **XPathNavigator** in C# its not correct.

```
public object Evaluate(string expression)
{
    try
    {
        var result = base.Evaluate("\"89001012012341234\" mod 97");
        **//Value of result=>20**
        var result1 = 89001012012341234 % 97;
       **//Value of result1=>22**
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception Exception)
    {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Value of result and result1 is not same why???

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `result` then?

Comment: result = 20 and result1=22

Comment: Thanks.  Did you want to pop that into your question :)  Make it easy for others to see

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath will be evaulated as `89001012012341234.0 % 97.0`, operands will have `double` type, not `int`. [See](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/ac67ffac987d0c27236c4a6cf1255c2bcbc7fe7d/src/System.Xml.XPath/src/System/Xml/XPath/Internal/NumericExpr.cs#L65) MOD operator implementation.